# Equivalent of Autofac's delegate factories in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container, autofac

I'm working on a project that has the MS Unity IOC framework well and truly baked-in.

There's a lot of code in which dependencies are created, but whose own dependencies are manually passed in. It forces the dependency to exist on the parent object where it doesn't necessarily need to.

I really miss Autofac's delegate factories, where I could take a dependency on a factory method in the form of a delegate.  Is there any way to do this in Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity supports [Automatic Factories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec32) which will inject a Func if it can resolve T.

However, out of the box there is no direct equivalent of Auofac's delegate factories.  You could probably create a Unity container extension to achieve similar functionality.